# Clarification regarding finding the degree of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have the field $\Bbb Q$  and then an extension of $\Bbb Q(\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$=$e^{\frac{2i\pi}{5}}$. Find $[\Bbb Q(\epsilon):\Bbb Q]$ and the basis. I've done similar problems where say the field was extended by$\sqrt3$ or something similar, so I used a similar approach for this problem.

I said the minimal polynomial of this appears to be $x^5-1$. I'm unsure how to proceed from this point, our solutions mentioned that since
$\dfrac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ is irreducible the degree of our field extension was thus $4$.

I'm unsure about this step, where did $x-1$ come from? I assume it has something to do with the roots of unity? How would I proceed from where I left off and then ultimately find the basis?

Also would the procedure for this question be different if it was $\epsilon=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{9}}$ or any other odd number in the denominator of the exponent?

Also as a semi-tangential question/clarification question. The degree of the field extension is the basis of the $\Bbb Q(\epsilon)$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ correct? But the BASIS itself are elements of $\Bbb Q(\epsilon)$ they are effectively the minimal elements we need to construct $\Bbb Q(\epsilon)$ via linear combinations right?

Comment: Note $1$ is a root of $x^5 - 1$, so clearly $x^5 - 1$ is NOT irreducible (as any minimal polynomial must be). That leaves you with $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ (the fifth cyclotomic polynomial) which IS irreducible. The procedure would indeed be different for a primitive 9th root of unity, since 9 is not prime.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. Obviously 1 is a root, so my polynomial is reducible just not entirely reducible. The connection between cyclotomic polynomials just made sense. Thank you very much, but if I may ask could you what the procedure for 9 or any non-prime root of unity be? 9 is a bad example since it can be factored by a difference of two square perhaps, however, I'm still confused then how we would proceed in another case. 

Why wouldn't the same trick, where in we divide by

Comment: Well you would still divide by $x - 1$. But $x^2 + x + 1$ is also a factor of $x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the minimal polynomial must be irreducible.  Note that $x^5 - 1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$: since $1$ is a root, then it has $x-1$ as a factor.  To get an irreducible polynomial, we divide out this factor, obtaining
$$
\frac{x^5 - 1}{x-1} = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed 1 as the root. It makes sense, I also now see the connection with cyclotomic polynomials in class.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, for the moment, that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ (this is not hard to prove). It follows that it splits over $\Bbb Q(\epsilon)$ as:

$(x - \epsilon)(x - \epsilon^2)(x - \epsilon^3)(x - \epsilon^4)$

since these are all roots of $x^5 - 1$. Moreover, by the irreducibility of the quartic, it should be clear that $\{1,\epsilon,\epsilon^2,\epsilon^3\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb Q(\epsilon)$ (because if this was not a linearly independent set, $\epsilon$ would satisfy a polynomial of lesser degree).

In this particular case, the Galois group is particularly nice: it is cyclic, and generated by the automorphism:

$\sigma:\epsilon \mapsto \epsilon^2$

(this is because $2$ is a primitive element of $(\Bbb Z_5)^{\times}$).

It turns out that the automorphism $\sigma^2$ corresponds to complex-conjugation, which clearly has order 2.

In general, the splitting field of $x^n - 1$ is going to depend on how divisible $n$ is, not whether $n$ is even or odd. More explicitly, the Galois group is going to have order $\phi(n)$, and is intimately connected with the group of units mod $n$.